# How to get Page Layout to appear on the ribbon

Tags: 2010

I am going to Site Actions > New Page in SharePoint 2010. I am not seeing the Page layout button on the ribbon. To get it to appear I thought I had to turn on the following:

- Site Collection Features turn on *SharePoint Server Publishing
- Infrastructure* Site Features turn on *SharePoint Server Publishing*

Is there anything else I need to do?

**Edit**
If I turn off *Wiki Page Home Page* as a site feature, creating new page seems to work. Confused to why this is the case.

Comment: I believe that Wiki pages do not support the Page Layout feature as the Publishing pages do.

Comment: Is there way you can make the add publsihing page to be the default type over wiki?

Comment: I think that if you make a site a publishing site it is the default, but I am not sure about team sites etc.

Answer (score 1):

On a teamsite for instance - do the following:

Activate the following features:

- Site Collection Features - SharePoint Server Publishing
- Site Features - SharePoint Server Publishing

~ Navigate to the **page library** (Pages) 
~ Create a **new page**
~ Set the new page as the **welcome page** of your site
~ Delete the **SitePages** library

From now on, you will fully use the publishing features (page layouts).